# Implementation of infix @ for lists

Tags: python, python-3.5

[PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) adds the @ infix operator for matrix multiplication. The lists however don't implement this as of now. Thus as directed by the documentation I tried to implement my own version of `__matmul__`.

This is my first attempt.

```
class Matrices(list):
    def __matmul__(self,matrix):
        tempmat = [[0 for row in range(len(self))] for col in range(len(matrix))]
        for i in range(len(self)):
            for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
                for k in range(len(matrix)):
                    tempmat[i][j] += self[i][k] * matrix[k][j]
        return tempmat

a = Matrices()
a.append([[1,2],[3,4]])     
b = Matrices()
b.append([[5,6],[7,8]])       
print(a@b)
```

However I am getting an error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(a@b)
  File "test.py", line 7, in __matmul__
    tempmat[i][j] += self[i][k] * matrix[k][j]
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

How do I solve this problem? That is, how do I implement the `@` character for lists in python?

Comment: Just an aside - if you want to implement matmul, you should use Strassen.

Comment: @erip I just wanted to learn the usage of `@` in python3.5. Anyway thanks for that. I will try to learn that. Thanks :)

Comment: Understood. Strassen is a faster alternative to `O(n^3)` - I think it's `O(n^2.8)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated for rewritten question**: Clearly, either `self[i][k]` or `matrix[k][j]` is a `list`, not an `int`. Looks like you were `append`ing in the code outside when you should have been `extend`ing.

**Original answer to first problem**:

You used `[[0 for row in range(self)] for col in range(matrix)]`, when you probably meant to wrap both `self` and `matrix` in `len` calls. Unless for some crazy reason you implemented `__index__` on your `Matrices` class, it's not a integer, so you can't `range` over it.

Comment: @BhargavRao: Deleting when it actually answers your original question is sort of bad form. Ask a new question, but don't delete just because you got an answer.

Comment: Ok fine thanks. I'll try your suggestion. Hope you don't mind my edit. I have +1d you. But do keep the latter half of the answer. :)

Comment: That said, you need to look at the error. Clearly, either `self[i][k]` or `matrix[k][j]` is a `list`, not an `int`. Looks like you were `append`ing in the code outside when you should have been `extend`ing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that edit. But can you please allow me to make your answer more suited for a general question and answer (for the general viewers) instead of addressing only me. (It may help others with the same problem)

Comment: @BhargavRao: Your issues were largely specific to your scenario. There isn't a general answer to the question, because different implementations will have different needs. `__matmul__` was added to support `numpy`, not really for general purpose Python use; making a whole consistent matrix class is well beyond the scope of a simple SO answer.